Screenshot of the Week #126
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 126th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! pinckerman's screenshot from hollow-knight won with 12 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-10-14, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-10-21, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No Theme
There is no theme this week.  BUT! Next week's theme will be Halloween as is tradition around here.  So perhaps gather a screenshot for that theme in advance!
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.


the-longest-road-on-earth

Thank you for the balance/harmony! ✨

@Artfaith Thanks! I'm a big fan of vertical shots, they look so nice in the sidebar :)

An epic Eikon fight in final-fantasy-16


This. This is why I hate shrinks.

katana-zero

For reference, this is a secret boss fight in Katana Zero. You can only get it by angering your therapist/handler at all possible moments, along with a couple of other stuff. You can find a more detailed guide here.

That is definitely NSFW in some way. I do not think that this should be pinned to the sidebar.

@FabianRöling Oh… should I change/remove it?

Not sure. I guess it is fine, as long as not too many people vote for it. :D

@FabianRöling Which is not really how that rule works, though :D I suppose it might fall under imagery of harm. But for a website aimed specifically at gaming, that seems a little non-sensical, as it can be expected. But I'm not sure. Let's see what the moderators have to say :)

("Imagery of victims". Just a few seconds too late for the edit window.)

My aluminum factory in satisfactory that takes a train ride back to my main base.


For some strange reasons, seeing your character holding some kind of remote control, reminded me of slot cars

@Clockwork that's actually a "medical inhaler" to heal you lol! It was the smallest thing I could hold to take up less screen space

elden-ring


To War! sins-of-a-solar-empire-ii


I know I posted the same game again, but can you blame me? Look how cinematic this is!

What am I seeing here?

@FabianRöling My fleet is performing warp jumps to jump to another planet.

Taken during fortnite Absolute Doom live event. Is there too much UI? Bunch of random players hanging out before the start of the event. Of course once the storm circle moved out we all started killing each other again but it was fun while it lasted.

